# Jackson: Is there a way to ignore 0/1 on Boolean deserialization?

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization, jackson-databind

I have a `JSON` object with a `Boolean` property that needs to allow only `true` or `false` during the deserialization.

Any value different of `true` and `false` should throw an exception.

How can I do that?

---

e.g.:

Valid json:

```
{
  "id":1,
  "isValid":true
}
```

Invalid json:

```
{
  "id":1,
  "isValid":1
}
```

---

#### Update

I tried what @Michał Ziober proposed and it worked fine.

As I'm implementing a Spring application (with Webflux) I just had to configure in a different way. I'm posting here what I did:

- Create a Configuration class extending from `DelegatingWebFluxConfiguration`
- Override the `configureHttpMessageCodecs` method setting the property on `ObjectMapper`

```java
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfig extends DelegatingWebFluxConfiguration {

    @Override
    protected void configureHttpMessageCodecs(ServerCodecConfigurer configurer) {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.disable(MapperFeature.ALLOW_COERCION_OF_SCALARS);
        objectMapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);

        configurer.defaultCodecs()
                .jackson2JsonDecoder(new Jackson2JsonDecoder(objectMapper));
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you de-serializing with hard-code or with a third-party package? If you're using a third-party package, ergo `newtonsoft` what package are you using?

Comment: @i-medina Have you thought writing your own JsonDeserializer?

Comment: @StéphaneJeandeaux Yeah, I thought about it. But I was wondering if there is an easier way than that, like a Jackson annotation, or configuration.

Comment: @xTwisteDx I'm using Jackson 2.9.8

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to disable [ALLOW_COERCION_OF_SCALARS](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/MapperFeature.html#ALLOW_COERCION_OF_SCALARS) feature:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.MapperFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.File;

public class JsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File jsonFile = new File("./resource/test.json").getAbsoluteFile();

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.disable(MapperFeature.ALLOW_COERCION_OF_SCALARS);

        System.out.println(mapper.readValue(jsonFile, Pojo.class));
    }
}

class Pojo {

    private int id;
    private Boolean isValid;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Boolean getIsValid() {
        return isValid;
    }

    public void setIsValid(Boolean valid) {
        isValid = valid;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Pojo{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", isValid=" + isValid +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException`: Cannot
>   coerce Number (1) for type `java.lang.Boolean` (enable
>   `MapperFeature.ALLOW_COERCION_OF_SCALARS` to allow)  at [Source:
>   (File); line: 3, column: 14] (through reference chain:
>   Pojo["isValid"])  at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:63)

Comment: In spring-boot project it can be set in application.properties: 
`spring.jackson.mapper.allow-coercion-of-scalars=false`

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's not a for-any-case implementation, but may be it'll be suitable for you:

```
public class TestBooleanDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Boolean> {

  @Override
  public Boolean deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext context)
      throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    String str = jsonParser.getText();    
    boolean val = Boolean.valueOf(str);
    if (!val && Objects.nonNull(str) && !Objects.equals("false", str.toLowerCase())) {
      throw new RuntimeException("invalid JSON");
    }
    return val;
  }

}
```

Since a `Boolean.valueOf` is a result of check of the `java.lang.Boolean#`

```
public static boolean parseBoolean(String s) {
    return ((s != null) && s.equalsIgnoreCase("true"));
}
```

here: `boolean val = Boolean.valueOf(str);` you'll check is it a `true` value or not. If not, you should check is it `null` or `false`: `if (!val && Objects.nonNull(str) && !Objects.equals("false", str.toLowerCase()))`
if it's not you can throw an exception whatever you need. Otherwise you'll return a boolean value