# How to make Jackson not parse 1 or "true" into boolean values?

Tags: android, json, jackson

i'm using JacksonMapper and ObjectMapper to serialize/deserialize values from JSON. The problem is that i have a map of boolean values that should only accept boolean json values and not things like 1 or "true". However, JacksonMapper seems to automatically convert those integer values or string values into boolean values. How can i make convert the json only when there's a boolean value?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jackson: Is there a way to ignore 0/1 on Boolean deserialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57778322/jackson-is-there-a-way-to-ignore-0-1-on-boolean-deserialization)

Comment: `MapperFeature.ALLOW_COERCION_OF_SCALARS` solves a problem for integers and strings. Which version do you use?

Comment: Yes, i've just read the code and tried this implementation. Sorry if at first i stopped at reading  the question! Now the problem is solved. Thank you!

Comment: Great, I'm glad to hear that! Please upvote related answer. We mark this question as duplicated.