# REST API allow only true and false in request body

Tags: java, spring, rest, jackson, lombok

I have an endpoint that has request body and inside the request body contains an object like this

```
"settlementDiscountInfo": {
"discountScheme": "beforeTax",
"taxAmount": 0,
"showDiscountInfo": false,
"settlementDiscounts": [
  {
    "discountPercentage": "",
    "discountValue": "11110",
    "untilDateTime": "2023-11-30T15:51:51.008Z"
  }
]
```

}

showDiscountInfo is boolean and I would like to receive only true and false values and throw and error message with the rest of the possibilities.

**And my java code is like below and I am not sure if there's any annotation in jackkson or lombok that restricts this variable to accept only true and false?** By default I have set it to true.

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public static class SettlementDiscountInfoJson {

    private SettlementDiscountRequestInfo.DISCOUNT_SCHEME_TYPE discountScheme;
    private Integer taxAmount;

    @JsonProperty("settlementDiscounts")
    private List<SettlementDiscountJson> settlementDiscountJson;

    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    private Boolean showDiscountInfo = Boolean.TRUE;

}
```

Right now it accepts any number, true, "true" as true

and

0, false, "false" as false

Answer (score 1):

From [Jackson: Is there a way to ignore 0/1 on Boolean deserialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57778322/jackson-is-there-a-way-to-ignore-0-1-on-boolean-deserialization)

You need to disable [ALLOW_COERCION_OF_SCALARS feature](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/MapperFeature.html#ALLOW_COERCION_OF_SCALARS)

Comment: is there a way to disable for a specific field? allow-coercion-of-scalars=false will disable for the whole application i guess